# TukeyHSD for non-pairwise comparisons

Tags: multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

Following this question: 
[Pairwise comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68538/pairwise-comparisons)

I'm not sure if I can perform a Tukey Honest Significant Difference test on the data I have. I've thought Tukey's method was only valid for pairwise comparisons, in which each factor has a multiple levels, and you would compare the means of those levels for significance.

I have N States, each of which have anywhere from 100-1000 ratings, to which I've averaged their ratings per-State to get the means for each State. Each individual rating is completely independent (so each rating only corresponding to a specific thing in that State, which makes me think that I can't use Tukey's method).

In table form, it would look like:

```
(State)      (Rating)
VA           69
VA           56
VA           78
TX           99
TN           84
TN           96
.
.
.
```

Which I have shrunk down to:

```
(State)      (Rating)
VA           67.6
TX           99
TN           90
.
.
.
```

Can I run a TukeyHSD test to see if I can (100-a)% confidently say which means are significantly different?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your situation. You can certainly run an analysis, however, if the ratings are of different things (eg, 'I like cars' in VA, 'math is fun' in TN, etc), the analysis won't mean anything.

Comment: The ratings are the same ratings, but each one is independent. So it is not the case that any given rating has a treatment in separate states, it is the case that every rating (within the same category) has no corresponding/related rating in another State